# Typescript problem with getting values of object

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I want to get values from

```
[{"code":"RRR","name":"Name","rate":"1.17","$key":"MeJy8ClJvJy"}]
```

I used `Object.values(obj)` and i am getting same

```
[{"code":"RRR","name":"Name","rate":"1.17","$key":"MeJy8ClJvJy"}]
```

while i tried using

```
    function* values(obj: string) {
      for (let prop of Object.keys(obj)) yield obj[prop as any];
    }
```

as well as

```
Object.keys(obj).map(k => obj[k as any]);
```

both these yielded me

```
 ["[", "{", "\"", "c", "o", "d", "e", "\"", ":", "\"", "R", "R", "R", "\"", ",", "\"", "n", "a", "m", "e", "\"", ":", "\"", "N","a","m","e" "\"", ",", "\"", "r", "a", "t", "e", "\"", ":", "\"", "1", ".","1", "7", .....
```

on chrome `Version 91.0.4472.164 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
but funny thing is using TS Playground log is same

```
[{"code":"RRR","name":"Name","rate":"1.17","$key":"MeJy8ClJvJy"}]
```

but if i am removing `[]` from this everything works fine and as i am intending it to work. But only problem, I am getting data in only this way. I am using `typescript 4.3.5` and `angular 12.1`. Thanks in advance

Comment: Object.values(obj[0]) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const data = [{"code":"RRR","name":"Name","rate":"1.17","$key":"MeJy8ClJvJy"}];
```

The `[]` as you call them, depict it's an `Array`. So you should use array functions for these. A `{}` indicates a plain object.

If you want to see all the values in the array, you will get a list of objects like this:

```
data.forEach((item) => console.log(item));
```

This will log an item for every item in the array.

---

If you want to see the values of the properties of the objects in the array, you can do the following:

```
data.forEach((item) => console.log(Object.values(item)));
```

---

A small but crucial hint. I'm all for starting with `TypeScript` instead of plain `JavaScript`, but first solidify the basic concepts of the language in your head, before starting something as big as Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Spread operator should do it -

```js
console.log(Object.values(...[{"code":"RRR","name":"Name","rate":"1.17","$key":"MeJy8ClJvJy"}]))
```